# Use of infinitude of primes in the Green-Tao theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers

In [a video](https://youtu.be/W1OkVkq2vFM) I watched last night on [nuking](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798215/) [mathematical mosquitos](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512), Matt Parker gave the following proof of the infinitude of primes: suppose there are finitely many primes. The [Green-Tao theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem) says there are arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions in the primes, hence there cannot be finitely many primes. Contradiction.

Leaving aside the slightly dubious and unnecessary use of proof by contradiction, it made me wonder whether or not this proof was circular (and Parker himself remarks: "Green and Tao took it as a given that there are infinitely many prime numbers and my pithy proof may very well be circular!"). Namely, is there some fact about the infinitude of primes that is used deep in the proof of the Green-Tao theorem? For instance, in some density arguments or similar?

Comment: I think this proof is not circular. On the other hand, as I recall, Green and Tao do use basic facts like $\zeta(s)$ has a pole at $s=1$ which implies readily that there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts#comment100823_42513

Comment: What they use about primes (Goldston-Yildirim result) is of course much much more than infinitude.

Comment: @PeterHumphries I already linked to that.

Comment: @FedorPetrov can you clarify?

Comment: Clearly this question is not doing well! I don't mind migrating it to M.SE, though clearly the people best placed to answer it would be here.

Comment: In a way the question appears to be answered in the question you link to as pointed out by @PeterHumphries Why is that answer not sufficient?

Comment: @quid ah, it would help if the link went to the specific comment that points out the relevant usage: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts?page=3&tab=active#comment100823_42513 I did in fact scan all the answers at that question to check if they already mentioned Green-Tao, but didn't have the patience to check all the comments too!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been answered in a different question (see comments).

Comment: @AndrásBátkai answered in a comment on an answer to a different question, which I've now extracted for ease of finding.

Comment: The majority of the proof comes from ergodic-theortical ideas which usually does not distinguish the primes(and actually in a later paper they've proved the Mobius-Nilsequences conj. which shows Mobius randomness in the settings of the dynamical systems they are considering).The primes come into play only on sect.$9$ in their paper,where they construct a psuedo-random measure.The infinitide of the primes can be seen implicitly in the pre-sieving step(W-trick),as you want $W$ to grow on $N$ (at-least morally) and not bounded a-priori,and more explicitly in Prop.9.1 they use Dirichelt's thm.

Comment: There is an elementary simple proof of the infinitude of primes by Euclid: Let $p_1,...,p_n$ be primes. Hence there is a prime divisor $p_{n+1}$ of $1+p_1\cdots p_n$ diffrent from the $p_i,i\le n$. So there is no need to use Green-Tao, Prime Number Theorem or the like.

Comment: @Todd I _am_ a mathematician, and if you check the links, you see that the point is that this is total overkill and purposefully so.

Comment: @Asaf that would have been a great answer!

Comment: These might be silly questions, but here goes nothing.  Doesn't a circular argument require assuming *a priori* the result to be proved?  Or does "circular" here really just mean "forgetful"?  If so, how do we measure "forgetfulness"?  (E.g. it seems that most here agree that proving that primes get arbitrarily large means that the argument required the infinitude of primes, but why is that exactly?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was in fact answered by [Thomas Bloom](https://mathoverflow.net/users/385/thomas-bloom) in [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts?page=3&tab=active#comment100823_42513) in response to exactly my question above (posed by Qiaochu Yuan):

> [Green and Tao] need to embed $[1,N]$ in $Z_p$ for some prime bigger than $N$ to get a nice field structure for some arguments to work.

At least this is a more visible answer to this question if people are searching for it!