# $S_M$ is not always homeomorphic to the 1-sphere of $F$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, operator-theory

Let $F$ be a infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space, with inner product $\langle\cdot\;| \;\cdot\rangle$, the norm $\|\cdot\|$, the 1-sphere $S(0,1)=\{x\in F;\;\|x\|=1\}$ and let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ be the algebra of all bounded linear operators on $F$.

> Let  $M\in \mathcal{B}(F)$ be a bounded operator. Suppose
>
> - that $M\in \mathcal{B}(F)^+$, i.e., $\langle Mx,x\rangle\geq0$ for all $x\in F$, and
> - that $M$ is an injective operator on $F$.
>
> Consider
> $$S_M(0,1)=\{x\in F:\;\langle Mx, x\rangle=1\}.$$

According to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293025/are-the-following-subsets-of-a-hilbert-space-always-homeomorphic) $S_M(0,1)$ is **always homeomorphic** to the 1-sphere $S(0,1)$.

> If $M$ is **not injective** ($M\ne 0$), I want to find an example such that $S_M(0,1)$ is **is not homeomorphic** to the 1-sphere of $F$ denoted $S(0,1)$.

I think if $F$ is an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space and if we find an operator $M$ such that $S_M(0,1)$ is compact then $S_M(0,1)$ is **not homeomorphic** to $S(0,1)$. Indeed $S(0,1)$ is compact iff $F$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: If $M$ is e. g. a projection, then if I am not mistaken $S_M(0,1)$ is the cartesian product of the 1-sphere for the subspace you project onto and the orthogonal complement of that subspace.

Comment: $M = 0$ satisfies your criteria, though it's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: @ArunDebray Yes $M$ is assumed non zero operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taras Banakh's answer to your original question essentially answers this one too. Take $F=l^2$ and take $M$ to be the projection on the first to coordinates. Then $S_M(0,1)=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3,...)\in l^2,|a_1|^2+|a_2|^2=1\}$, which is homeomorphic to $S^1\times l^2$, where $S^1$ - the usual circle.

Then the unit sphere of $l^2$ and $S^1\times l^2$ are not homeomorphic, since the former is simply connected (easy to see), and the latter is not: its fundamental group is the product of the fundamental groups of $S^1$ and $l^2$ and is therefore isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Could you please explain me why the unit sphere of $l^2$ and $S^1\times l^2$ are not homeomorphic?Thanks a lot

Comment: I kind of do explain in the body of the answer: the unit sphere of $l^2$ is simply connected, while $S^1\times l^2$ is not.

Comment: Could you please explain me why the unit sphere of $l^2$ is simply connected however $S^1\times l^2$ is not? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The explanation of the second claim is already written in the answer.  The unit sphere of $l^{2}$ is simply connected, because of stereographic projection: draw a loop, take a point not on that loop, stereographically project the sphere on $l^2$ with respect to that point, deform the obtained loop to a point, then project the homotopy back. I hope this explanation makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reference to cite it?i.e.  A reference where i find  the resultat  that explain why  the  unit sphere of a hilbert space is simply connected. Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any

Comment: According to this link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space  The $1$-shere of $l^2$ is always contactible. On the other hand $S_M(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to  $S^1\times l^2$. Could you please help me show that  $S^1\times l^2$ is not contactible?

Comment: It's not contractible because it's not simply connected. The latter claim is proven in the answer.