Elementary consequences of famous technical theorems and/or conjectures
Recently, Will Sawin gave a perfect answer to my question about elementary consequences of Langlands program. Then Timothy Chow asked a similar question about non-abelian class field theory, and received several answers.
Inspired by this, I would like to ask, more generally, what other famous/important technical theorems and/or conjectures have not-too-famous consequences with elementary statements? Here, by "not-too-famous" I mean that, at the very least, the consequence is not stated in the paper where the theorem was proved (or conjecture formulated). By "elementary statements" I mean explainable to undergraduate students, possibly after a few preliminary definitions. Of course, I am interested in cases when the statement of the original theorem/conjecture is far beyond the undergraduate level.
As an example, are there consequences with elementary statements of (a) Hodge conjecture, and (b) Yang–Mills existence and mass gap problem? These are the Millenium Prize Problems with quite technical statements.
For consequences from theorems, I may mention, for example, recently proved Brauer's Height Zero Conjecture. I classify its formulation as above undegraduate level. Are there elementary consequences?

If someone has in mind specific technical theorem or conjecture for which you are particularly interested to learn an elementary consequence, please mention it in a comment and I may add it to the question as another example.

Well, if Yang-Mills theory didn’t have a mass gap, the world would be very different.

This is pretty well-known, so I am posting it just as a comment and not an answer, but the Jacobi triple product is a particular case of the Weyl-Kac character formula for Kac-Moody algebras: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_character_formula#Weyl%E2%80%93Kac_character_formula

How do you define technical?

"Technical" is defined by sentence "Of course, I am interested in cases when the statement of the original theorem/conjecture is far beyond the undergraduate level." For example, the Borsuk–Ulam theorem and The Robertson-Seymour theorem are not "technical" by this definition, while Frey-Mazur conjecture is.

Hirzebruch and Zagier have a book, The Atiyah-Singer Theorem and Elementary Number Theory, which might contain examples of what you're looking for. See also Hirzebruch's paper, The Atiyah-Bott-Singer fixed point theorem and number theory.

If we pretend undergrads understand Riemannian geometry, then we have this paper which used Langlands reciprocity to resolve a (relatively elementary) problem in hyperbolic geometry. See also this overview by Emerton.


The Robertson-Seymour theorem states that the graph minor order is a wqo. Put more simply, in any infinite set of graphs, one is a minor of another. Admittedly, this doesn't really match the letter of the question because the statement is not hard to explain at an elementary level, but I find it relevant because the proof is extremely deep, famously spanning a series of twenty papers published over two decades and totalling over 500 pages. (Besides, I see how this could be seen like a “worthless intellectual puzzle” by students.)
The theorem has the elementary consequence that every minor-closed property of graphs (i.e., a property such that if a graph has the property then all its minors do as well) is algorithmically decidable (in cubic time, even). This is because the set of minimal obstructions to the property (graphs which do not have the property although all their minors do) is an antichain for the minor order, therefore must be finite by Robertson-Seymour, so the algorithm just has to check that the graph doesn't have any graph from a finite list as a minor. For example, we automatically get the polytime recognizability of planar graphs, cactus graphs, graphs embeddable in a given surface, etc. (more examples). (An amusing aspect is that we can obtain non-constructive decidability proofs, see these course notes for a discussion with further examples.)

Martin's Borel determinacy theorem can be explained roughly at the same level at which you are able to start measure theory (so probably not first-year undergrad), took 20 years to be proved, and has a relatively difficult proof (it was nicely explained by Timothy Gowers in a series of five blog posts starting here). An elementary consequence is the determinacy of many simple types of games, e.g., Büchi games, parity games, or more generally all ω-regular games.
For completeness, a Büchi game is played on a finite graph with a distinguished start vertex; players take turns to move a token (initially on the start vertex) along an edge, and one player tries to make a certain set of vertices hit infinitely often. Parity games are similar but with an integer priority on each vertex, the winner being determined by the parity of the highest priority of a vertex visited infinitely often. The game being determined means that whatever the game arena, one of the players has a winning strategy. This should all be explainable even to non-mathematical people.
(For more elementary proofs that these particular games are determined, and much more, see the wonderful recent textbook Games on Graphs directed by Nathanaël Fijalkow).



One particularly amusing example of nonconstructivity coming from Robertson-Seymour - we don't even know the set of obstructions to being embeddable in a torus, though we know it has at least 250000 elements. This also indicates that while asymptotically fast, the constants will typically make it infeasible in practice

If one assumes a sufficiently strong form of the Frey-Mazur conjecture (see eg the discussion below Theorem 1.3 of this paper), then the equation $x^p+y^p+31z^p=0$ (where $x,y,z$ are integers and $p\geq 5$ is a prime) has no nontrivial solutions beyond multiples of $(-1,2,-1)$, $(2,-1,-1)$ with $p=5$.
This text describes some known results about this equation, for instance the fact that it only has solutions for $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, and that the above solutions are the only ones for $5 \leq p \leq 10^6$.

For something less conjectural (and relying on older, far less difficult results that modularity questions), I’m reminded of the following problem I was told about a couple of years ago: show that $1/x+1/y+1/z=11$ has infinitely many rational solutions with $x+y+z=1$.
I was told that there is an elementary argument, but here’s a natural and direct proof with the following facts:

an elliptic curve (defined as a smooth projective plane cubic in Weierstrass form over a field) has an abelian group law,
the Nagell-Lutz theorem.

The equation is birational to the elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ with Weierstrass equation $w^2=r^3+r^2-45r+100$, so it is enough to show that $E$ has infinitely many rational points.
Suppose this is false, then $E(\mathbb{Q})$ has only torsion points (here, we’re using the group law of an elliptic curve).
Note that $E$ contains already the points $\{\infty,(3,\pm 1),(-5,\pm 15),(0,\pm 10),(4,0)\}$ (the points come from the intersections with the axes and the original solution $\{x,y,z\}=\{1/2,1/3,1/6\}$).
But you can check directly that the above equation is smooth mod $3$, so $3$ does not divide the discriminant of the cubic – so by Nagell-Lutz $(5,15)$ cannot be a torsion point, whence the contradiction.
(We can also reach the same conclusion by directly comparing the images of the known points in $E(\mathbb{Q})$ – assumed to be all torsion – in $E(\mathbb{F}_3)$ and $E(\mathbb{F}_7)$, which have exactly $6$ and $12$ elements respectively, since the reduction mod $p$ morphism is an injection on the prime-to-$p$ torsion.)

There is a thread, which I can't find, either here or on mathstack, about proofs that use more high-powered tools than they need, things like using Fermat's Last Theorem to prove the irrationality of $\sqrt2$. I think this example would go well in that thread.

@GerryMyerson https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts ?

@GerryMyerson: are you thinking of the first or the second example? (The second example gets even better if you use Mazur’s theorem and a computer to check that there are at least $17$ rational points on the elliptic curve.)

@Jean, yes, that's the one.

The second example, Aphelli.

An example could be the Borsuk–Ulam theorem, which implies that on the earth, if we may represent it by a sphere, there are always two antipodal (exactly opposite) points with equal temperature.

I would classify the Borsuk–Ulam theorem itself as a statement explainable to undegraduates. The consequence is of course even more elementary, on the level of general audience, possibly without higher education.

There are even two antipodal points with equal temperature and pressure...

What's so elementary about the Earth? It took us millenia to even see its poles.

For just same temperature, you can do much more easily, by considering some great circle and using IVT. As eddy says, you even have antipodal points with same temperature and pressure. That is literally just a restatement of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem in 2 dimensions then though (assuming temp and pressure are continuous), merely phrased in "physical" terms, so I don't find it a very compelling example.

It has been shown by Jafar Shaffaf and independently Terry Tao that the Bombieri–Lang conjecture implies a negative answer to the Erdős–Ulam problem, which asks if there exists a dense subset of the Euclidean plane whose pairwise distances are all rational numbers.
